# How can I order my JSON by a string date?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an app which pulls data from a JSON. The order of the JSON is important as the app presents its data in the order of the JSON.

I've created a separate app to create a JSON object, add it to the rest of the JSON and upload it. The problem is that it adds it to the top of the JSON file. I want to reorder the JSON before it is uploaded by its date value.

My JSON is in this format:

```
{
"articles":
    [                       
        {
            "title":"Title 3",
            "url":"URL 3",
            "date":"04/01/17"
        },  

        {
            "title":"Title 2",
            "url":"URL 2",
            "date":"03/01/17"
        },  

        {
            "title":"Title 1",
            "url":"URL 1",
            "date":"02/01/17"
        },  
    ]
}
```

The date is a string in dd/MM/yy format. If I add the articles in order then there's no problem as the newest one will always be added to the top, however I sometimes add articles from previous days which I'll want to slot into a previous place.

Is there a way to order the JSON before it is uploaded via the date value?

Comment: Although your JSON value may be coming out in the order you put them in, you shouldn't depend on that since dictionaries are unordered. I'd recommend using an array within your JSON articles key then sorting that array by date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's already array, just need to subtract it, convert to `Date`, and compare them, pretty easy:

```
let articleArray: [[String:String]] = dict["articles"]!
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"

dict["articles"] = articleArray.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return dateFormatter.date(from: first["date"]!)! < dateFormatter.date(from: second["date"]!)!
}
```

**SwiftyJSON**:

```
if let articleArray = json["articles"].array {
     let sorted = articleArray.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
        return dateFormatter.date(from: first["date"].stringValue)! < dateFormatter.date(from: second["date"].stringValue)!
     })
 }
```

Comment: This looks awesome, and definitely what I'm trying to do. I'm having some trouble getting the articleArray though. I'm using SwiftyJSON so my json is in JSON format and I can't figure out how to convert it to the array or the dict. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I think I've sorted it, I've added my answer in case it helps anyone.

Comment: @ghertyish updated with swiftyJSON, you can use it's function for easier subtract value, you dont need to cast the type around with it, move `dateFormatter` out of the block so it wont need to recreate multiple times

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is definitely the way to do it, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Just realised, should the date format for the month be: "dd/MM/yy"